# How to get the bounded element DOM from an observable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to get the Element DOM from an observable object.
Please look on this example.

I'm clicking on the button **"Get Class"** and then I want to get **valueB** DOM element.

Please pay attention that I want valueB DOM element and not buttonA

***Example:***

**HTML**

```
<button id="buttonA" data-bind="event:{click: getClassFromValueB}">Get Class</button>
<input id="valueB" class="Hello" data-bind="value: observables.idNumber"/>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
"
"
"
observables : {
    idNumber: ko.observable('SomeText');
},

getClassFromValueB : function(child, event){
    idNumber_DOM = this.getElementDOM(this.observables.idNumber);
},

getElementDOM : function(observable){
    **//WHAT TO DO HERE????**
}
"
"
"
```

**I seeking a solution without jQuery...**

```
$(event.target).closest('#valueB')
```

**UPDATE:** The main reason for this question is to to clear a customized attribute in a input when one of the other inputs are change
Example:

```
<input id="InputA" class="Hello" data-bind="event:{change: clearInputB}"/>
<input id="InputB" class="Hello" data-bind="value: observables.idNumber"/>
<input id="InputC" class="Hello" data-bind="event:{change: clearInputB}"/>
<input id="InputD" class="Hello" data-bind="event:{change: clearInputB}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for but maybe you can solve the problem in a different way. If you're after a DOM element's class, Knockout provides a [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html). valueB's data-bind statement would look something like this:

```
<input id="valueB" data-bind="css: observables.valueBClass, value: observables.idNumber"/>
```

Then you can have another observable named valueBClass where you can set valueB's class as well as retrieve it from other observables.

```
valueBClass = ko.observable('Hello');

getClassFromValueB = function() {
    var theClass = observables.valueBClass();
}
```

You're on the right track to keep the DOM and the model separate. This is an important concept that is sometimes missed when using Knockout. As a result of keeping them separate, you would not reference any DOM elements anywhere in your Knockout model. You would only reference observables.

Comment: I familer with the css attribute, but what I need to actually do is to clear a customized attribute in a input when one of the other inputs are change...

Comment: What you may need is custom bindings. This should give you access to the element and/or its properties from which you can customize behavior and control interactions with DOM elements. See [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).